# Create a POJO from Database View using Hibernate plug-in for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa, pojo

I have a web app, and I need to generate a POJO from a database view. I've already created some POJOs using the Hibernate plug-in for Eclipse but only for existing tables not for a view. Does any one knows how can I create a POJO from a view?

Thanks in Advance

Software I'm using:

- JSF 2.1
- Hibernate 4.0
- Eclipse Kepler Java EE

Answer (score 0):

There was no big issue, Hibernate plug in detects views as common tables so the procedure was the same.

Hopes this can help some one,